# how to get $F'(x,y)$ from $F(x,y)$ in taylor approximation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Hi I would to know is there's a rule  to get $F'(x,y)$ from $F(x,y)$ in Taylor's approximation

and if so, then what is it ?

$f(x,y)= 3x^2y$ and $f'(x,y) = 6xy +9 x^4y$

$f(x,y) = 2x^2-y$ and $f'(x,y) =4x -2x^2+y$

I think first we should perform the partial derivative respect to$ x $

then I don't know what is the next step.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format question instead of adding photos.

Comment: thanks I'm sorry this is the first time :)

Comment: Tell us what you mean by $f'(x,y)$.